# What cause IBM Kubernetes cluster to send signal to kill

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have a new kubernetes cluster in IBM Cloud and it  has only one application (MongoDB) deployed, but the pod log shows that after it is started and ready for connection, it gets a kill signal to terminate.

Why the cluster send the kill signal? There is no other applications in it.

````
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T12:39:03.999+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23378,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by kill(2)","attr":{"pid":0,"uid":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-22T12:39:03.999+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23381,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"will terminate after current cmd ends"}```
````

Comment: Please add more details, so that others can understand the question. What type of Kubernetes cluster (VPC?) and version? How did you deploy the app? What is in the IBM Cloud logs, what in the Kubernetes logs?

Comment: It is classic custer
Version: 1.24.8_1544
I deployed the mongodb using: "helm install mongodb-cogssm bitnami/mongodb -f values.yml"

IBM Cloud, the worker nodes and worker pools are green. How to get the logs?
The Kubernetes, the log from the pod has been pasted to the question itself. Mongodb was starting and ready for connection, then 20 seconds later, it get the kill signal.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use $kubectl describe pod {podname}, I see the following events:

```
Warning  Unhealthy         3m5s (x8 over 4m15s)   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: /bitnami/scripts/readiness-probe.sh: line 9: mongosh: command not found
  Normal   Pulled            2m55s (x2 over 4m24s)  kubelet            Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.10-debian-10-r20" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           2m55s (x2 over 4m24s)  kubelet            Created container mongodb
  Warning  Unhealthy         2m55s (x6 over 3m45s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: /bitnami/scripts/ping-mongodb.sh: line 2: mongosh: command not found
  Normal   Killing           2m55s                  kubelet            Container mongodb failed liveness probe, will be restarted
```

This mongodb has no mongosh command for the liveless probe.